# MS Excel 2016 / Can't find options when I append 2 tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using Excel 2016 Version.

When I try to append 2 tables in a sheet after making the connection in a power query form, I see other people have the option to append 2 tables or append more than 3 tables. But mine only provides the format in the image.

Anyone knows what's the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Window shows in my computer.

[image]

The option I Wanna see is the image below.

The one that I want to find.

[image]

All I see is the image with the options on the internet.

Comment: Not sure but per **[Microsoft Documentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/append-queries-power-query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a)** you should have the feature.